# PySNMP not finding existing existing JUNIPER-SMI module

Tags: pysnmp

O'm trying to compile some Juniper MIBs for PySNMP using the `mibdump.py` tool. It seems like it cannot find the existing `JUNIPER_SMI` module that is in the `pysnmp-mibs` package.

The module appears to exist:

```
root@2a614c91783e:~# ls -al /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pysnmp_mibs/JUNIPER-SMI.py 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 10690 Dec 11 23:03 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pysnmp_mibs/JUNIPER-SMI.py
```

The output of `mibdump.py` says that is is using `pysnmp.smi.mibs` and `pysnmp_mibs` as existing packages:

```
root@2a614c91783e:~# /usr/local/bin/mibdump.py --mib-source /mibs/JuniperMibs --mib-source /ibs/StandardMibs --mib-stub mib-jnx-bgpmib2.txt mib-jnx-exp.txt
Source MIB repositories: /mibs/JuniperMibs, /ibs/StandardMibs
Borrow missing/failed MIBs from: http://mibs.snmplabs.com/pysnmp/notexts/@mib@
Existing/compiled MIB locations: pysnmp.smi.mibs, pysnmp_mibs
Compiled MIBs destination directory: /root/.pysnmp/mibs
MIBs excluded from code generation: mib-jnx-bgpmib2.txt
MIBs to compile: mib-jnx-exp
Destination format: pysnmp
Parser grammar cache directory: not used
Also compile all relevant MIBs: yes
Rebuild MIBs regardless of age: no
Dry run mode: no
Create/update MIBs: yes
Byte-compile Python modules: yes (optimization level no)
Ignore compilation errors: no
Generate OID->MIB index: no
Generate texts in MIBs: no
Keep original texts layout: no
Try various file names while searching for MIB module: yes
Created/updated MIBs: 
Pre-compiled MIBs borrowed: 
Up to date MIBs: 
Missing source MIBs: JUNIPER-SMI, SNMPv2-CONF, SNMPv2-SMI, SNMPv2-TC
Ignored MIBs: 
Failed MIBs: JUNIPER-EXPERIMENT-MIB (no module "JUNIPER-SMI" in symbolTable at MIB JUNIPER-EXPERIMENT-MIB)
```

Python and package versions:

```
root@2a614c91783e:~# pip list
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
pip (9.0.1)
ply (3.10)
pyasn1 (0.4.2)
pycryptodomex (3.4.7)
pysmi (0.2.2)
pysnmp (4.4.2)
pysnmp-mibs (0.1.6)
setuptools (36.6.0)
wheel (0.30.0)
root@2a614c91783e:~# python --version
Python 3.6.3
```

Not sure what I am missing here. Am I missing something obvious that doesn't let me detect existing modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mibdump.py` tool will search for already existing `JUNIPER-SMI.py` to save on `JUNIPER-SMI.txt` compilation. If you have another MIB dependent on `JUNIPER-SMI.txt`, then already compiled `JUNIPER-SMI.py` won't help.

If you just add `--mib-source http://mibs.snmplabs.com/asn1/` parameter to your `mibdump.py` command invocation, the tool will fetch all the required ASN.1 MIBs from the URL above and compile them into .py.